# JSP update page on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I've written a .jsp file whose contents should be updated on click of the button. I tried using appendChild of Javascript but it's not working as this is a .jsp file. 
Here's the code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Hello World!</title>
</head>
    <p id="demo"><h1> Hello,   </h1>

<body>
<br/>Firstname:<input type="text" name="firstname">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<%= request.getParameter("firstname")
%>
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        var node=document.getElementById("demo");
        document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(<%= request.getParameter("firstname")%>);
    }
</script>



 </body>
 </html>
```

I want the output to be " **Hello, Dia**", If Dia is entered as the firstname and when Enter button is clicked. The firstname should be appended to Hello, !

Comment: assign dynamic data into one variable then pass variable as arugument  in to appendChild method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed `scriptlets` inside script . javascript is a client side technology.

While scriptlets are executed in application servers when you compile (they are nothing but the java codes)

Try this ,

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        var node=document.getElementById("demo");
var value=<%= request.getParameter("firstname")%>;
        document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(value);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , the click of your button does not take you back to the server , so you wont need to access the value of the text field using a scriptlet , you can do this in plain HTML and Javascript

as follows :

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Hello World!</title>
</head>  

<body>
<div id="demo"><h1> Hello,<div id="displayName"></div>   </h1></div>
<br/>Firstname:<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
document.getElementById('displayName').innerHTML = firstName.value;
}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```